# Calculate roots of characteristic equation of symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have 3 data matrices A,B,C (all 3x3), with which I use the following code to calculate roots of D(p)X = 0

```
syms p
D = A + B*p + C*(p^2)
solP = double(solve(det(D)))
```

From this, I get 6 values for solP. But when I try substituting it back into the symbolic matrix D, as follows, I get non-zero values of det(D) sometimes

```
for i = 1:6
  p = solP(i)
  det(double(subs(D))  % Should be zero always as we are substituting roots
end
```

Please help me understand this behaviour.

EDIT ::
Example :

```
A =

   1.0e+11 *

    4.8976    7.0936    6.7970
    4.4559    7.5469    6.5510
    6.4631    2.7603    1.6261

B =

   1.0e+11 *

    3.9223    7.0605    0.4617
    6.5548    0.3183    0.9713
    1.7119    2.7692    8.2346

C =

   1.0e+11 *

    6.9483    0.3445    7.6552
    3.1710    4.3874    7.9520
    9.5022    3.8156    1.8687

solP =

    0.1061 + 0.0000i
    1.5311 + 0.0000i
   -0.3432 + 0.9356i
   -0.3432 - 0.9356i
    0.4228 - 0.5465i
    0.4228 + 0.5465i

det(D) =

   2.2143e+19
  -5.4911e+20
  -8.6415e+19 + 4.5024e+19i
  -8.6415e+19 - 4.5024e+19i
  -1.4547e+19 + 9.1135e+19i
  -1.4547e+19 - 9.1135e+19i
```

Comment: How big are the non zero values? Note that `solP` is a numerical value. Can you also provide us some sample matrices `A`, `B` and `C` for which the problem occur?

Comment: @m7913d The matrices A, B and C are of 1e11 order. I have added an example. I'm thinking it fails for large numbers. Is there any way around it? Or some other method which could be used to accomplish the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the [relative accuracy of floating point values](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), typically `1e-16`.

The input matrices are of the order `1e+11` - `1e+12`, the solution is of the order `1e+0`, so the elements of `D` are also of the order `1e+11` - `1e+12`. To calculate a [determinant of a 3x3 matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#3_.C3.97_3_matrices), one should take products of three matrix elements and add/subtract them. So, each term is of the order of `1e+33` - `1e+36`. If you subtract such a values to obtain the determinant, the expected accuracy is in the order of `1e+17` - `1e+20`. Indeed, this corresponds with the values you get. Given the relative accuracy, you are not able to reach further to zero.

Note that if you scale your input matrices, i.e. divide it by `1e+11`, the solutions are indeed the same, but the determinants are probably more what you would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found a workaround by checking the rank of the matrix. The rank comes out as 2 even if the determinant is non-zero, which is good enough to ascertain that the matrix is singular.